# HTML variable in <a> for href

Tags: html, django, django-templates

In my HTML, I want to have the text of a href to be the same as the variable each_files_configs. Whatever I try seems to come out as a literal.

```
  {% for each_files_configs in files_configs %}
    <p></p>
    <a href="{% url 'download_file' %}">document.write(each_files_configs)</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

I have also tried `<var>` and all it does is change the text to italics.

Comment: What templating engine is this? Looks like Jinja or django templates

Comment: This is django.

Comment: Use `{{ expression }}` to insert the return value of a expression into a template

Comment: Client side JS (like `document.write`, a function that should almost never be used anyway) goes in `<script>` not `<var>` and doesn't have access to variables defined in your Python program that finished running on the server a few seconds earlier and send the HTML document to the browser.